# t-sql group by category and get top n values

Tags: t-sql

Imagine I have this table:

```
Month | Person | Value
----------------------
Jan   | P1     | 1
Jan   | P2     | 2
Jan   | P3     | 3
Feb   | P1     | 5
Feb   | P2     | 4
Feb   | P3     | 3
Feb   | P4     | 2
...
```

How can I build a t-sql query to get the top 2 value rows and a third with the sum of others?

Something like this:

```
RESULT: 
Month | Person | Value
----------------------
Jan   | P3     | 3
Jan   | P2     | 2
Jan   | Others | 1 -(sum of the bottom value - in this case (Jan, P1, 1))
Feb   | P1     | 5
Feb   | P2     | 4
Feb   | Others | 5 -(sum of the bottom values - in this case (Feb, P3, 3) and (Feb, P4, 2))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the assumption you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher, using a CTE would do the trick.

- Attach a `ROW_NUMBER` to each row, starting with the highest value, resetting for each month.
- `SELECT` the top 2 rows for each month from this query (rownumber <= 2)
- `UNION` with the remaining rows (rownumber > 2)

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH Months (Month, Person, Value) AS (
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P1', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P2', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P3', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P1', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P2', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P3', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P4', 2
),
q AS (
  SELECT  Month
          , Person
          , Value
          , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Value DESC)
  FROM    Months
)
SELECT  Month
        , Person
        , Value
FROM    (        
          SELECT  Month
                  , Person
                  , Value
                  , RowNumber
          FROM    q
          WHERE   RowNumber <= 2 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT  Month
                  , Person = 'Others'
                  , SUM(Value)
                  , MAX(RowNumber)
          FROM    q
          WHERE   RowNumber > 2        
          GROUP BY
                  Month 
        ) q                          
ORDER BY
        Month DESC
        , RowNumber
```

*Kudo's go to Andriy for teaching me some new tricks.*

Comment: @Andriy: *you can't have them all...* <vbg>

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH atable (Month, Person, Value) AS (
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P1', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P2', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 'P3', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P1', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P2', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P3', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 'P4', 2
),
numbered AS (
  SELECT
    Month, Person, Value,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Value DESC)
  FROM atable
),
grouped AS (
  SELECT
    Month, Person, Value,
    Grp = CASE WHEN rownum < 3 THEN rownum ELSE 3 END
  FROM numbered
)
SELECT
  Month,
  Person = CASE Grp WHEN 3 THEN 'Others' ELSE MAX(Person) END,
  Value = SUM(Value)
FROM grouped
GROUP BY Month, Grp
ORDER BY Month DESC, Grp
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, OP needs the top 2 *Value* rows (I overlooked it too). The ORDER BY Person should become ORDER BY Value.

Comment: @Lieven: Seems like we all overlooked that. *Experts...*

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH NTable AS
(
    SELECT [Month],
                   Person,
                   Value,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Month] ORDER BY Value DESC) 
                       AS Rownumber 
            FROM MyTable
)
SELECT  t.[Month], 
        CASE Rownumber WHEN 1 THEN t.Person WHEN 2 THEN t.Person ELSE 'Others' END As Person, 
        SUM(t.Value) As [Sum] 
FROM NTable t
GROUP BY t.[Month], CASE Rownumber WHEN 1 THEN t.Person WHEN 2 THEN t.Person ELSE 'Others' END
ORDER BY t.[Month]
```

Comment: I believe you meant `ORDER BY Value DESC` (in the CTE), otherwise it works, +1.

Comment: @Andriy M: Why would I order by value? AFAIK the values can be anything. The final ORDER BY is subject to change, depending on the needs of the OP, so I concentrated on getting the correct data rows, with ORDER BY month just to improve readability.

Comment: @Andriy M: OK, I see it, OP wanted the top 2 values. I'll change my post.

Comment: Andriy meant the ORDER BY in the ROW_NUMBER function, not from the result.