# How to write a T-SQL query to select top 1 records for each client?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple script that I am trying to get the most recent records per client on.  How do I do this in TSQL?  This is my code currently, however, this is only selecting one record total.  This one record displays most recent record for ALL clients and not EACH client!  How can I reformulate this please?

```
SELECT TOP 1
C.ClientID, actual_date
From ClientRecords C
WHERE (@ClientID is NULL or C.Client_ID = @ClientID)
Group by C.ClientID, actual_date
ORDER BY C.actual_date
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091747/t-sql-group-by-category-and-get-top-n-values

Answer (score 4):

*Aggregate* the column by using `MAX()` function on  *actual_date*

```
SELECT  C.ClientID, MAX(actual_date) max_DATE
From    ClientRecords C
WHERE   (@ClientID is NULL or C.Client_ID = @ClientID)
Group   by C.ClientID
ORDER   BY C.actual_date
```

Comment: Heh, if I knew you were going to edit so quickly, I wouldn't have bothered to answer.  But what do you mean some random client per group?  This will give the max date for each clientid, which is what is asked for if I understood the question right?

Answer (score 1):

This has not been tested, but it should look something like:

```
select 
c.clientId, max(actual_date) as Actual_date
from clientrecords C
group by c.clientID
order by c.clientID
```

That will give you the highest actual date for each client, ordered by the clientId.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I found a little more satisfactory solutoin to this:

```
WITH rs AS
(

SELECT 
C.ClientID, actual_date,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.ClientID, actual_date)rid
From ClientRecords C
)

SELECT * FROM rs WHERE rid =1
```

Comment: Yes, ROW_NUMBER is often used to solve this kind of problems. Note, however, that someone would likely have suggested this solution sooner if you specified that you were using a DBMS that supports window functions. (`tsql` is not enough as it implies more than one product, as well as more than one version thereof.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBQUERY for that purpose:

```
SELECT 
    C.ClientID ,
    (SELECT MAX(C1.actual_date) FROM ClientRecords C1 WHERE C1.Client_ID = C.Client_ID) AS MaxDate
FROM ClientRecords C
WHERE (@ClientID is NULL or C.Client_ID = @ClientID)
Group by C.ClientID, actual_date
ORDER BY C.actual_date
```