# Visualize all products of the order with the highest value, to extract the largest amount and orders from it

Tags: sql

```html
 Desired result
    NAME                  PRICE
Lenovo X1 Carbon           4009.00
Lenovo ThinkVision X1    1549.00
Lenovo YOGA 520          1349.00
Motorola Moto Z2           999.00
Motorola Moto Z          549.00
Motorola Moto E5          179.00
```

```html
ID  CATEGORY    NAME                            PRICE   ORDER_ID
1   PC          Lenovo ThinkaPad L380            1579     5
2   Mobile      Motorola Moto E5                 179      1
3   Mobile      Motorola Moto Z                549    2
4   Monitor     Lenovo ThinkVision X1            1549   4
5   PC          Lenovo X1 Carbon                 4009     3
6   Mobile      Motorola Moto Z2                 999      4
7   PC          Lenovo Legion Y530             2099   4
8   PC          Lenovo YOGA 520                 1349    3
9   Monitor     Lenovo ThinkVision X1            1549   6
10 PC           Lenovo YOGA 520                1349     6
11  Monitor   Lenovo ThinkVision X1         1549      3
12  Mobile    Motorola Moto Z2               999      3
13  Mobile    Motorola Moto E5               179      3
14  Mobile    Motorola Moto Z                   549   3
```

[image]

I used these 2 queries to extract information from the table in the photo
but i need to find a way to retrieve the information with just one query please help

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME , PRICE, ORDER_ID 
FROM PRODUCTS
ORDER BY PRICE DESC

SELECT NAME ,PRICE
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE  ORDER_ID like '%3%'  
ORDER BY PRICE DESC
```

Desired result

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the first query in your example. That columns do you want to output?

Comment: I want to select the name of the highest purchase, price, and all products from this order

Comment: One query returns a fixed set of columns.  One of your queries returns two columns and one returns three columns.  Hence, the question is not clear.

Comment: Show sample data and desired result as text tables, not image.

Comment: Solution is dependent on database used. Add tag for database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a T-SQL query to select top 1 records for each client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343278/how-to-write-a-t-sql-query-to-select-top-1-records-for-each-client)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Get everything from the table 
SELECT 
  *
FROM
   Products

-- Where the total order value for the order is the highest
Where  
   order_id = 
(
    -- The largest order total
    SELECT TOP 1
        order_id
    FROM 
        Products 
    GROUP BY 
        order_id 
    ORDER BY 
        SUM(price) DESC
)
ORDER BY 
   Price DESC
```

Comment: THIS STILL DOESN'T HELP

Comment: Try running above query again, I made a fix to it. Or see my other answer, it finds the order_id of the highest priced item , and retrieves all name and price for every other item in that order. It is combining your two queries you posted into one. It all depends if you want to get items of the highest single priced item, or the highest order sum.

Comment: @ПетяЯнева-Цветкова they both work, but they have different function, the shorter one finds order by single highest price (one item), the second looks at the total order value for each order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME ,PRICE
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ORDER_ID =
(     
    SELECT TOP 1 ORDER_ID   
    FROM PRODUCTS
    ORDER BY PRICE DESC
)
```