# Delete all but the newest N table rows in each category (multiple categories are combined in a varchar)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table of news articles, and each article can appear in several categories. Sadly these categories have been stored as text values concatenated in a single varchar for each row.

**I would like to keep the top 5 news articles in each category, and delete the older ones. I don't think it can be done without procedural code (a SQL loop/cursor, or where SQL is called repeatedly by an external program which knows all possible category names).**

Here's my test data, without the news article title/content. I believe the code needs to remove the unwanted category strings first, and then delete all rows that have had all their categories removed.

```
declare @News table(ArticleId INTEGER NOT NULL, DateAdded SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, Categories VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL)  
insert into @News values (11, '2014-01-11', 'SPORT~CELEBS~')  
insert into @News values (10, '2014-01-10', 'SPORT~CELEBS~POLITICS~')  
insert into @News values (9, '2014-01-09', 'SPORT~CELEBS~')  
insert into @News values (8, '2014-01-08', 'SPORT~NATURE~')  
insert into @News values (7, '2014-01-07', 'SPORT~CELEBS~')  
insert into @News values (6, '2014-01-06', 'SPORT~CELEBS~POLITICS~') --ought to have SPORT label removed  
insert into @News values (5, '2014-01-05', 'POLITICS~')  
insert into @News values (4, '2014-01-04', 'POLITICS~')  
insert into @News values (3, '2014-01-03', 'POLITICS~')  
insert into @News values (2, '2014-01-02', 'POLITICS~') --ought to get deleted  
insert into @News values (1, '2014-01-01', 'CELEBS~') --ought to get deleted

--magic happens  

delete from @News where Categories = ''  
select * from @News order by DateAdded desc
```

If the only solution is to use `WHILE` or `CURSOR` then I will opt to wrap the SQL up in a stored procedure and call it repeatedly with a value of 'SPORT~' then 'CELEBS~' then 'POLITICS~' etc.

Comment: "Sadly these categories have been stored as text values concatenated in a single varchar for each row" - time to fix the problem rather than the symptoms?

Comment: Unless fixing that problem requires code more horrible than what I'm asking above!

Comment: @MagnusSmith What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: We're on SQL2008. Ideally I like to use the solution within Phonegap too, which adheres to http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/ , but I doubt that is possible!

Comment: possible duplicate of [t-sql group by category and get top n values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091747/t-sql-group-by-category-and-get-top-n-values)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate questions as that link does not suffer the problem of categories being concatenated together in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a partial (and very inelegant) solution. The approach is to recreate the sort of 'glue' table that might exist if this was a sane database in the first place (though a proper table would have two FKs).

```
--create list of all possible category values (get first category from every row, then second, then third, etc)
declare @Category table (SingleCategory VARCHAR(50))
insert into @Category
select distinct LEFT(SingleCategory, charindex('~', SingleCategory))
from (
    select categories as SingleCategory from @News
    union
    select SUBSTRING(categories, charindex('~', categories)+1, 100) from @News where Categories like '%~%~'
    union
    select SUBSTRING(categories, charindex('~', categories, charindex('~', categories)+1)+1, 100) from @News where Categories like '%~%~%~'
    --repeat if 4 and 5 occurances possible, etc
) sq

--create a 'glue' table
declare @Glue table(ArticleId INT NOT NULL, DateAdded SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, Category VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
insert into @Glue 
select articleid, dateadded, SingleCategory
from @News n
inner join @Category c on n.categories LIKE '%' + c.SingleCategory + '%'

--use the glue table to identify the articles we do want, and delete all the others
delete from @News where ArticleId not in (
    SELECT articleid
    FROM (
        SELECT articleid, Category, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY dateadded DESC) AS RankThem
        FROM @Glue
    ) sq
    WHERE RankThem <= 5
)
```

This gets rid of the two rows we don't want, but we end up with 6 articles in the SPORT category, so it isn't a perfect solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: In the end I made use of a loop in the calling code which happened to know what the values of the Categories column were. I was then able to call a simpler bit of SQL repeatedly.